# Replacing joda time with time api in hibernate entity

Tags: hibernate, timestamp, timezone, jodatime, java-time

I am currently upgrading from jodatime to the javatime api in a project. The project is using hibernate version 4.3.1 and jadira.usertype for mapping between org.joda.time.DateTime and java.sql.Timestamp (http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype.core-hibernate36/apidocs/org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/joda/PersistentDateTime.html).

An excerpt from one of the entities:

```java
@Column(name = "created_at")
private DateTime createdAt;
```

When the server system time is "Fri Feb  7 10:09:02 CET 2020", 
this gets stored to the column: "2020-02-07 09:09:02.431000"

In the joda time conversion guide (https://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html) it is stated that org.joda.DateTime is the same concept as java.time.ZonedDateTime. I am thinking about just replacing DateTime with ZonedDateTime, but there are two things that cause concern and problems: the new java.time types are not supported in the hibernate version and the column data type of "created_at" is "timestamp without time zone". Upgrading hibernate is not an option, yet.

I am thinking about using java.sql.Timestamp instead of org.joda.DateTime for the entity column

```java
@Column(name = "created_at")
private Timestamp createdAt;
```

But unsure about which java.time type to use instead of org.joda.DateTime when converting from/to Timestamp - any recommendations on how to go about this are appreciated!

Comment: Looks like Hibernate supports the new java.time types as of version 5.2.  But also before that they had an optional `hibernate-java8` package to add that support.  If you can't upgrade, can you use that older (now deprecated) package?

Comment: Using java.time is a step forward, I understand. Using `Timestamp` is a step *backward*, I see no reason why you should want that. That class is poorly designed and long outdated.